# Renderizar View para uma string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Peguei um codigo aqui mesmo no stack para renderizar uma view para string.

Quando a view a ser convertida esta no mesmo contexto ou seja, na mesma pasta da controller funciona normalmente, porem se tento renderizar uma view que esta em outro controller não funciona.

**Alguem faz ideia de como posso renderizar uma view que esta em outro Controller?**

```
    public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        //aqui mudei o codigo para tentar chamar um Controller fora do contexto atual, mas não rolou
        Controller controller = new PedidoController();

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Isso](http://www.datahaunting.com/mvc/render-a-razor-view-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/%22Isso%22) te ajuda? Espero que esse link possa te esclarecer alguma coisa. A única coisa é que está em inglês.

Answer (score 0):

este codigo cai no mesmo problema que eu tinha..

Eu fiz algumas mudanças e consegui fazer pelo menos chamar a View, porem agora o problema esta sendo ao passar uma ViewBag para a View...

Alguém sabe me dizer porque?

Segue metodo alterado.

```
        public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        Controller controller = new PedidoCompraController();
        var wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
        var routeData = new System.Web.Routing.RouteData();

        if (!routeData.Values.ContainsKey("controller") && !routeData.Values.ContainsKey("Controller"))
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", controller.GetType().Name
                                                        .ToLower()
                                                        .Replace("controller", ""));

        controller.ControllerContext = new System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext(wrapper, routeData, controller);

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```